# Error: package javax.annotation does not exist after upgrade to lombok 1.16.2

Tags: java, android, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

My android project builds fine with lombok 1.16.0, but once I change my dependency to target 1.16.2, I get the following error everywhere I'm using a lombok annotation:

`Error:(20, 1) error: package javax.annotation does not exist`

The Android SDK does not include all javax packages. What I'm wondering is if this is a bug in 1.16.2 or do I now have to add a dependency to `javax.annotation`?

Note: This is in Android Studio with Lombok plugin 0.8.8

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can disable the generation of `javax.annotation.Generated` by putting the following line in a `lombok.config` file in one of the top directories of your project:

```
lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation = false
```

See the [configuration documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) for more information.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok Developer.

Comment: Lombok config doesn't exist or work with Android Studio currently right?

Comment: @RoelSpilker You´re a lifesaver man. Thanks a lot for Lombok, it´s a must-have in every good developer toolkit! ;-)

Comment: @serkan lombok.config works fine with Android Studio it seems

Comment: @serkan you can create lombok.config file in android studio and then put this line.

Comment: lombok.config file does not exist, and creating it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 26):

If you're facing same issue in Android Studio using gradle - add following line to build.gradle:

```
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Comment: Why `10.0-b28` as opposed to `3.1.1` or `3.2-b06`? 10.x appears to be 3 years _older_ than the other versions.

Comment: Using a GlassFish dependency doesn't seem right. I prefer `compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0` per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25090868/577062). Though, `jsr250-api` is rather old (2007). Note: I am using Dagger 2, not Lombok.

Answer (score -2):

The right answer for android development today is to use a version of dagger which is greater than 2.1 (because of the [fix](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/95) mentioned by @tomrozb is integrated in 2.1)

Comment: This is a lombok issue, not a dagger issue