# Lombok Requires Annotation Processing

Tags: android-studio, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 7, and the Lombok plugin suddenly started saying:
`Annotation processing seems to be disabled for the project X`, and providing a link to settings.

[image]

Clicking on the notification does not take me to the right place.

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The Settings opened by clicking the notification are the `Per Project` settings, and those are not what you need in this case.

To fix this, go to

- `File->Other Settings->Default Settings`
- Expand `Build, Execution, Deployment`
- Expand `Compiler`
- In `Annotation Processors` check `Enable annotation processing`
- You may need to re-open the project to get the settings to take effect.
- Enjoy

For complete reference - screenshot with appropriate settings screen:
[image]

Comment: This only worked AFTER I removed the project from the Recent List (what shows when you start AS) and then re-add it.

Comment: To be completely sure:  Close the project. Delete the project from "Welcome to Android Studio" dialog (click the X). Click "Configure" in the bottom right and enable annotation processing as described above. Open your existing Android project again. Described in this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38698186/1666063

Comment: Changing Default Settings has zero effect unless you are creating a new project. The settings are already written in .idea/ And removing your project from the welcome screen does nothing to it. (Yes, I tried. It had zero effect. Then I realized it doesn't even make sense. :)
/peace

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba not true. I just removed from the welcome dialog and readded. Problem was fixed. That is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 19):

With the newer gradle versions, it is enough to type these lines into the app's build.gradle's dependencies block:`

```
compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
```

Sync the project with the gradle and it will work.

Comment: THis worked flawlessly for me on Android STudio 3.0 Canary 4, gradle-4.0-rc-1

Comment: Thank you. I tried a lot of another answers with butterknife and other. This helped me a lot

Comment: Thanks that is solved my issuse ,Build was enable to run using gradlew but without gradle itself

Answer (score 16):

First, I don't think removing your project from the welcome screen can have any effect. Just think about it, removing your project from "recent projects" on that screen does not re-create it, how could changing Default settings have any effect on **an existing project?**

To enable annotation processing in an existing project you don't need to delete anything. Go to `YourAwesomeProject/.idea/compiler.xml` and make sure you have value "**true**" in following attribute: `/project/annotationProcessing/profile@enabled`.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    ...
    <annotationProcessing>
      <profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="true"><!-- here -->
        <processorPath useClasspath="true" />
      </profile>
    </annotationProcessing>
  </component>
</project>
```

You might need to **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Comment: Tried this and thought it works but it doesnt. Upvoted it aswell for the idea setting the compiler options, but it seems to store the data in the cache.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold the point about caches is a good one, updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Much simpler and more resilient than the approved answer.

Comment: `how could changing Default settings have any effect on an existing project?` I don't know why, but it does work to remove it from the welcome screen, I just tried it.

Answer (score 7):

For those who have the same problem using Android Studio 2.4+ its not solved by doing any hints above except Janis Peisenieks answer.

Open your Intellij IDEA 2017 / Android Studio 2.4+ and go to (Windows)

1. File->Other Settings->Default Settings
2. Expand **Build, Execution, Deployment**
3. Expand **Compiler** and choose **Annotation Processors**
4. Make sure you have **Enable annotation processing** and "**Obtain processors from project classpath**" enabled
5. Last but not least update your projects build.gradle file with the snippet below. Ignore the hint that its deprecated, since it's not using (until now. See [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140579)).

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       javaCompileOptions {
           annotationProcessorOptions {
               includeCompileClasspath = true
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Found out that there is a very simple way doing this without all those changes above!**

If you set your processor in the gradle like lombok you wont use only **provided** or **testCompile**. You need to add this using **annotationProcessor** aswell into your dependencies. Example:

```
dependencies {
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
}
```

Thank you to Jack Wharton for butterknife where i figured out how he solved it.

**Hint**: You may need to invalidate cache and restart to get it working for some annotation processors like lombok.

Comment: Upvoted for the second half of your answer, fiddling with settings that are used for newly created projects makes no sense IMO :) /peace & thanks for the point about caches again

Comment: Point No 5. Worked for me

Comment: There is no `File / Other serttings` in Intellij 2020

Answer (score 5):

Probably marked answer was sufficient at the time but I struggled a bit with android studio 3 and lombok 1.16.18. Anyway following worked for me

in `app` > `build.gradle` add following

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
```

you may start getting other errors so if you in your `MyApplication` > `lombok.config` add following lines

```
lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation = false
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true
```

if you don't have `lombok.config` just added it

Above were suggested by the developer of lombok in following posts
[addGeneratedAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28473188/806076)
[suppressConstructorProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020733/806076)

Answer (score 3):

The setup guide from the lombok website([lombok set up for android](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android)) says we should do two things

> 1, install the lombok plugin
>
> 2, add gradle dependencies
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>   compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
>   annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
> }
> ```

But for me the plugin causes the problem to occur. After I disabled the plugin the error went away and lombok still works.

Answer (score 3):

As of Android Studio v3.5 (august 2019) and prior, there wasn't setting for annotation processor.
It is however sufficient to define in build.gradle in dependencies section :

```
dependencies {
...
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
...
}
```

If Android studio still complains about "Lombok Requires Annotation Processing", for me it was Lombok plugin reinstallation and "Invalidate Caches / Restart" that fixed the problem.

Comment: reinstall lombok plugin and invalidate caches with restart helped me

Answer (score 1):

In **AndroidStudio 3.5+** do next steps:

- go to `File -> Other Settings -> Preferences for New Projects... (!)`
- expand `Build, Execution, Deployment`
- expand `Compiler`
- select `Annotation Processors`
- check `Enable annotation processing`

If it still wouldn't work just reinstall Lombok plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Follow what setup manual says:

> Gradle Make sure that the version of your android plugin is >= 0.4.3
> Use the gradle-lombok plugin. If you don't want to use the plugin, add
> Lombok to your application's dependencies block (requires Gradle v2.12
> or newer):
>
> ```
> dependencies {    
>  compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18" 
> }
> ```
>
> Android Studio Follow the previous instructions (Gradle). In addition
> to setting up your gradle project correctly, you need to add the
> Lombok IntelliJ plugin to add lombok support to Android Studio:
>
> 1. Go to File > Settings > Plugins
> 2. Click on Browse repositories...
> 3. Search for Lombok Plugin
> 4. Click on Install plugin Restart Android Studio

https://projectlombok.org/setup/android

Answer (score 0):

1. install Lombok plugin and restart
2. add dependencies : https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

   compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
   annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

   testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
   testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

this is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to:

> file => setting => Build,Execution,Deployment => Compiler => Annotation Processor

check: Enable annotation processing

[image]