# How to enable Annotation Processor in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

This is the error notification I'm getting 
[image: This is the Error]

And when I go to the described Location I cant find it

[image]

Comment: Have a look here...[Enabling Annotation Processor for Android 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642712/enable-annotation-processors-option-in-android-studio-2-2)

Comment: not working for me, I have already seen that thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lombok Requires Annotation Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911888/lombok-requires-annotation-processing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to close the project and access to the default preferences from the "Welcome to Android Studio" page and you will can find the "Annotation Processors" section.
More info at other questions about Android 2.2 (for example
[enable Annotation Processors option in Android Studio 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642712)) where you can also find other tips like removing al projects from welcome page, using invalidate cache and restart and so on.
Anyway it seems that Lombok APT properly runs regardless of the boring message. The bug has been already issued at https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/264.

I finally have found the tweak!
It seems that the problem is when you create the project **before** enabling annotation processors.
Exit from Android Studio and edit the file `<your project folder>/.idea/compiler.xml`.
You should find:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
        ...
        <annotationProcessing>
            <profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="false">
                <processorPath useClasspath="true" />
            </profile>
        </annotationProcessing>
    </component>
</project>
```

You should set `enabled` to `true` and the boring message disappears!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
        ...
        <annotationProcessing>
            <!-- This is the line where to set enabled to true  -->
            <profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="true">
                <processorPath useClasspath="true" />
            </profile>
        </annotationProcessing>
    </component>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the option under File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors

Answer (score 1):

1. Android Studio - File - Close Project
2. Configure - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Compiler - Annotation Processors - Enable annotation processing.
3. Open Project - Build - Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 0):

I was like this, you can find my way to set up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy from @Tudor Pop amswer
This is the right answer android-studio-2-3.
You can find the option under File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors

Answer (score 0):

For me in Android Studio 3.4.x works by enabling annotation processing through the following steps:

1. File - Close Project
2. Configure -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors - Enable annotation processing

Then you need to add the compiler.xml file to the .idea folder in the project folder. This is what compiler.xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    <annotationProcessing>
      <profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="true" />
    </annotationProcessing>
  </component>
</project>
```