# Annotation Processors is absent in Compiler Android Studio for Lombok plugin

Tags: android, android-studio

I've faced with the next problem:

I've installed the Lombok Plugin and it requires `Annotation Processing`

[image]

**Problem:**

Unfortunately i don't have this tab in `Compiler`

[image]

This question resolves the problem, but unlike me, they able to access this tab

[Lombok Requires Annotation Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911888/lombok-requires-annotation-processing)

My Android Studio version is 3.1.2.

Can anybody help me please?

Thank you!