# Warning about "Lombok Requires Annotation Processing"

Tags: java, android, plugins, lombok

i have configure my project on android studio thats use "Lombok" Plugin, i have download Lombok plugin on my IDE Android Studio, i've add compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6', implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'and annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'...even adding it on my default config build graddle app

javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }

but it still showing message "Annotation processing seems to be disabled for the project "OptimalRouteFinder". But lombok is on classpath.For the lombok plugin to function correctly, please enable it under bla bla bla"

What i have to do?

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911888/lombok-requires-annotation-processing

Comment: brother, actually i've read that answer but still not help, so i still asking this question

Comment: Did you try to replace 'compileOnly' with 'provided', and enable annotations at the IDE?

Comment: How to enable annotations at the IDE? I have searched the Android Studio Settings but still can't find it?

Comment: according to the [official document](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android) - you need to search for lombok plugin, install it and restart the IDE. Enabling annotations are related to Intellij IDE.

Comment: done, still doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

`Go to File -> Other Settings -> Settings for New Project`.

Next, go to `(Build, Execution, Deployment) -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors` and hit `[x] Enable annotaion processing`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for answering, I clarified your answer, note that you can add images using `Ctrl+G`

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue running in circles.  Setting only as Dennis described does not resolve the issue.  Accompanying it by replacing 'compileOnly' with 'provided' in the build.gradle makes the warning go away, but Android Studio then complains that 'provided' is deprecated and replaced with 'compileOnly'.  I guess I have to ignore the latter warning, then.

+++++++++
Sorry, with 'provided' it doesn't work either.  This is an unsolvable issue to me.